# Titanium iphone sdk

Tags: ipad, titanium

On iPhone simulator titanium application works fine, but on device splash screen freeze. Already desabled the ANALYTICS option, but not work. Can anyone help me?
what are the causes of application to be freezed at splash screen on device with titanium? And also  can you please suggest me: How to debug and rectify memory leak in titanium?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anybody can resolve the problem related to Application freezing.

Answer (score 3):

open your build/iphone/ directory and open the *.xcodeproject file in Xcode and use it to get to the debug or crash logs on your phone so you can see why it's crashing on the device.

Also any code you can post would be extremely helpful

Comment: Thanks, i got the solution for that. Actually I was using wrong database path.